# Prevent ContentObserver from getting a "specific" change on URI

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, contentobserver

I have an app that allow users to edit the `ContractsContacts` DB.

When a user edits the `ContractsContacts` DB using the functions of my app, I don't want that my `ContentObserver` is aware of that changes.

I want my `ContentObserver` to be aware only of changes generated from other apps. For example when users edit `ContractsContacts` DB by using the mobile apps.

So, my question is: is there a way to tell the `ContentObserver` *"hey, don't listen to this change, because I'm aware of it, dont call your `onChange()` method"*:

The only solution I found is:

1. **unregister** the `ContentObserver` before starting the "edit function" of my app
2. **register** again the `ContentObserver`  after my function did all its work.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not your `ContentProvider`, and so you cannot prevent Android from updating registered observers. Your observer is nothing special to Android.

So, in addition to your unregister-modify-register flow, you could tell your observer to ignore the next update (have it track that in a `boolean` or something), then modify the data. The observer would skip whatever work it normally does when that `boolean` is set, just flipping it to `false` to pick up future changes.

Both of these suffer from race conditions (you and another app modifying the provider at the same time).

Ideally IMHO, you modify whatever logic is being triggered by the observer to live with triggers coming from your own updates, so that all changes of the data are treated equally, whether coming from your app or not.